# When is 'over and above' used?

Tags: expressions, prepositions, word-usage

When is the expression 'over and above' used instead of just 'over' or just 'above'?

Comment: The only context where I would be absolutely certain to use ‘over and above’ as more than just a more emphatic version of either ‘over’ or ‘above’ is in the more or less set phrase _(to go) over and above the call of duty_. And even there is be more inclined to use the more common phrasing, _above and beyond_.

Answer (score 1):

The Oxford English Dictionary gives these definitions for *over and above* as a preposition:

1. Above in rank, in a superior position to; higher or greater than.
2. In addition to, besides.
3. More than; in excess of.

As an adverb it is defined as ‘Additionally, furthermore’. That use is rare, but in some regional speech in the UK and US it is used to modify an adjective or adverb with the sense ‘exceedingly, too much, too.’

Its use as an adjective with the sense ‘overmuch, too great, excessive’ is obsolete and rare

Comment: This doesn't really address when you'd use "over and above" instead of just a single word. For example, [TFD](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/over+and+above) also lists meanings pretty much in line with "more than; in excess of", with this example sentence: _I'll need another twenty dollars **over and above** the amount you have already given me._ But why not: _I'll need another twenty dollars **over** the amount you have already given me_ – doesn't that pretty much mean the same thing? I think that's what the O.P. is asking.

Comment: Doesn't 'over **and above'** add emphasis?

Comment: I think so, but maybe that ought to be part of the answer. I think the O.P. was looking for something over and above the accepted definitions. P.S. (to the O.P.) I think you could have elaborated on this more in your question, and maybe even have asked this on ELL, depending on the kind of answer you were hoping for.

Answer (score 0):

The following two examples from Google seem to suggest an emphatic, expansive connotation:

> we'll need another gallon [/??cup] of milk over and above what we
>   already have
>
> Ali Agca had probably sensed that over and above his own power, over
>   and above [??his skill at tiddlywinks] the power of shooting and
>   killing

["Over," as was said](http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=140), indicates superiority or transcendence . . .

The next example clarifies what is being modified (the whole phrase) better than the individual words would:

> The payment of and level of allowances, over and above salary or
>   wages, is a matter for agreement between the employer and employee

The twinned expression is rarely used with locational or directional senses, except for clever catchphrases:

> Over and Above Photography.